# Can I get aws cloudfront distribution report(csv) by sdk api?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm looking for some method to get report(*.csv) of CloudFront distributions.

Unfortunately, CloudFrontClient of AWS SDK doesn't support that function.(Or I could not find it.)

How can I get that informations by AWS SDK?

Comment: Are you talking about the reports that are available in the console, or something else?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes. I'm talking about that reports.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several [reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/reports.html) that can be accessed in the CloudFront console.

The reports are derived from the [CloudFront access logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html), and access logging can be configured so that the raw logs are stored automatically in S3 where you can access them.

From the access logs, you can derive the same information is in the console reports, but **the reports available in the CloudFront console can *only* be accessed from the CloudFront console.**  There does not appear to be a reporting API.

This is an unusual design for an AWS service, since most things you can do in the console are simply mapped to a documented API method, which the console is invoking in the background on your behalf.  Here, that isn't the case.

I would prefer to have found a more convincing citation than the one that follows, in order to justify the assertions above, but I have not found what I was looking for.  Note the omission of any mention of API access to the reports.

> You can access all our reporting options by visiting the Amazon CloudFront Reporting & Analytics dashboard in the AWS Management Console.
>
> You can also choose to receive even more information about the traffic delivered by your Amazon CloudFront distribution by enabling CloudFront access logs.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/reporting/